# Details about isomorphism between tangent vectors and directional derivative.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the book Introduction to smooth manifold lee page `53` it says there is an isomorphism between tangent vectors at the point $a$ and the directional derivative. My question is when we get a directional derivative, we just use the direction and unit vector in that direction. So how it can be an isomorphism when for example for the function $f(x,y)=2xy$ and vectors $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ we have the same directional derivatives?

Comment: You can extend the directional derivative from unit-vectors to vectors of arbitrary length by the natural scaling. For example, just use $df(v) = \nabla f(a) \cdot v$ for the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$. This use of unit-vectors is to streamline the concept for calculus III.

Comment: Notice the directional derivative given in the answer does not assume vectors of unit-length. The unit-length thing is native to multivariate intro. calculus. Advanced calculus texts, for example Edwards' text, describe a directional derivative based on arbitrary length vectors. My copy of Lee is at school, I'll take a look if I remember Monday.

Answer (score 2):

The standard directional derivative is given by,

$$D_v (f) = \sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \cdot v_j $$

Thus, $D_v: C^{\infty}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ and moreover $D_v$ is linear and obeys the Leibniz rule i.e $D_v$ is a derivation on $U$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the set of derivations on $U$ and consider the map $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathcal{D}$ defined by $v \mapsto D_v$.

One can easily show $\mathcal{D}$ is a vector space and so you are left to show that $\Phi$ is a linear-isomorphism. This the isomorphism that Lee is referring to. Thus you can view tangent vectors as derivations and from the above,

$$\textbf{e}^j \mapsto D_{\textbf{e}^j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}:= \partial^j$$

Later you will see that $\{\partial^j: j =1,...,n\}$ forms a basis for $T_pM$ where $M$ is a manifold and $T_pM$ denotes the tangent space. What's going wrong with your example is that you aren't considering the correct isomorphism. You are taking $v$ and associating it to $D_vf$ which is not well-defined if $f$ is allowed to vary. The correct thing to show is that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $D_v$ are isomorphic as vector spaces, but this is now clear since they are both $n$-dimensional.